# Strange Views Relationship Error

Tags: views

I've done quite a bit of googling and can't seem to find any information on this error, so I'm going to assume it's not a common one.

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined property: views_handler_relationship_broken:: $alias
>   in EntityFieldHandlerHelper::query()  (line 84 of
>   /MYPATH/sites/all/modules/entity/views/handlers/entity_views_field_handler_helper.inc).

A bit of information about my set up, I've been using Views to show a list of my Drupal Commerce Product displays, set up similarly to Commerce Kickstart where you have the Product Display that references the Commerce Products via the SKU. This error arose shortly after removing some fields relating to a relationship the view was using, as these fields no longer exist they cannot be re-added.

I've cleared the views cache, the site cache, to no avail. Is there any kind of database entry that may be referencing this particular relationship still?

Regards, Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling views debugging in views advanced settings I was able to narrow down the actual view with the error and it wasn't the one I had first suspected, oops! Note for anyone coming into similar problems, views debugging is amazingly helpful alongside Devel.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you shouldn't remove fields that are used by other mechanisms, like Views. Now when it's done, the best way I know is to export view, manually remove fields that was deleted from it, and re-import. And don't forget your backups.

Comment: After deleting the entire view and recreating it from scratch the error persists.